# PHP Session ID uniqueness (for use in a cookie)

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm writing a user system where users will log in using Twitter's API, then I'll store the information in a database along with a few extra pieces that I have the user put in.  I want the user to be able to come back after logging in and not have to log in again.  I decided that I'd get all the relevant information about the user, save it to the database, then save the session ID and user ID to another table.  Finally, I'd set a cookie on the user's computer containing the same session ID so that throughout their browsing they would stay logged in.  Then if they closed the browser and revisited the site later, I would read that cookie, get the compare it with the sessions table, get the User ID, and reconstruct the session (updating the sessions table with the new session ID).

My question is, how random is the session ID?  Is there a possibility that a user might get the same session ID that a user that hasn't visited the site in a week (so the cookie would still be active) had assigned to them?  If this happens, then the server might mistake the new user for the old one.  I really would like to avoid using the IP address because people might visit the site from a mobile browser where the IP can change at any time.

Any ideas on this?  I just want to ensure that user A and user B, separated by any amount of time, won't get the same session ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Append current time in microsecond to the unique id...

```
session_id() + microtime();
```

So not only would the session_ids have to be the same, it would have to happen on the same microsecond... making the vanishingly unlikely just about impossible. The only way to guarantee it 100% is to check this random value against all existing session ids and re-roll it if it already exists.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  I already needed the time for my script, so I simply changed time() to microtime(true).  For operations where I just need a timestamp I just floor() it, for the session, I do md5(session_id() . $time).  The MD5 is just to force it to always have a constant length of 32 characters.

Comment: First, please mark an accepted answer if you are satisfied with one. Second, a warning about hashing... as in crocodilewing's answer, the session_id() function is an MD5 hash itself, with 128 bits of data. Adding the $time and hashing it again will NOT add randomness because there are still only 128 bits available. Two different values can have the same hash.

Comment: I understand that, but the way I see it, an MD5 collision is less likely than the same PHP session id being used twice in a two week period.  My PHPSESSID is 26 characters long, but I'm not sure that it's that long every single time, sometimes it might be longer or shorter.  The MD5 of the session id and microtime is only there to force it to a 32 character length.  I could simply md5 the session ID, but adding the microtime to it just adds one more thing a potential attacker will have to figure out, both the session id and the microsecond at which it was hashed.

Answer (score 4):

Although the probability of having two active sessions with identical identifiers at the same time is vanishingly low (depending on the [hash function](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function)), you could add an additional (pseudo-) unique value to that session ID to get a value with both characteristics.

You could use [`uniqid`](http://php.net/uniqid) that fulfills the latter:

```
uniqid(session_id(), true)
```

`uniqid`’s value is based on [`microtime`](http://php.net/microtime) with an additional pseudo-random number from [`lcg_value`](http://php.net/lcg_value) and an additional source for more entropy that all together guarantees unique values.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP Session ID is an MD5 hash, which makes it 128 bits in length.  That's something like 340,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 different possibilities.  The odds of two people getting the same one are pretty remote.

If you want to guarantee uniqueness, put something in their cookie based on sequential numbers.

Comment: Remote, but not zero. To force a 1-in-a-million hash collision chance, you only have to generate around 10^16 hashes. Not trivial, but not impossible either.

Comment: So that's everyone on Earth signing up for a hundred million accounts each.  Yeah, best make it 256 bits just to be sure ;-)

Comment: At the rate things are getting IP-enabled, we'll start running into this once the insect kingdom gets connectivity. A kajillion ants pounding on a kajillion keyboards will not only write Shakespeare,but hack everyone's online banking sessions to boot.

Comment: A cryptographic hash function does not imply uniqueness. Add a (pseudo-) unique value to the hash value to get a value that has the characteristics of both.

Comment: Unfortunately, MD5 is [collisions-prone](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value), as shown in the link, and this is much easier to do than visiting values in a 2^64 range (would that be possible, see link).